# Filter on values to ignore instead of values to show

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro to create a table and filter out certain values on the 9th column. I want to show all results, `except for Taxes and General`. The generated code works the other way round and filters on the fields you do want to see.

How can I switch it around so I hardcode the values I don't want to see. So when a new value is added it is automatically picked up too, otherwise it is left out.

```
LastRow = Sheets(Sheets(1).Name).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:T" & LastRow), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
    Array("Intel", "Cisco", "Global", "Local", "HR", "Finance", _
    "Cables", "HP"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. That's not how AutoFilter works, and it's not about VBA.

See [how to use AutoFilter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-AutoFilter-to-filter-your-data-7d87d63e-ebd0-424b-8106-e2ab61133d92). VBA lets you manipulate the properties of the filter, not define new ways for it to work.

Your best chance will be to use another macro to update the filter with new values. You can choose if you want that macro to be user activated, or triggered by an event such as `Worksheet.Change`.

Comment: @CustomX That's no so terrible. It won't be a very difficult macro to write (and of course you can record a "bootstrapped" macro to just edit changes).

Comment: yeah, but won't that give me the same result in the end? it will always ignore the new items in the list too?

Comment: @CustomX - What I meant was that your macro should iterate the values and dynamically create the new filter. Again, not a click of a mouse, but not something that can't be done with VBA.